# How do I disable OPTIONS method on Django Rest Framework globally?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to disable `OPTIONS` method on my API built with Django Rest Framework (DRF) globally (on all the API endpoints)

currently an `OPTIONS` call returns,

```
{
  "parses": [
    "application/json",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "multipart/form-data"
  ],
  "renders": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "name": "Login Oauth2",
  "description": ""
}
```

which is something that I don't want someone to peek into. I want to return a blank character  as github does on its API or something else.

I tried

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def my_method(request):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return Response()
```

on an function based view, which returns an  but inspecting the headers show,

```
Allow →POST, OPTIONS, OPTIONS
```

which has a repeated `OPTIONS`.

How do I achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

In your settings, add something like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': None,
}
if DEBUG:
    # the default value
    REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS']: 'rest_framework.metadata.SimpleMetadata'
```

You can implement your own metadata class as well. Setting this to None will make it return HTTP 405 on `OPTIONS` requests.

Answer (score 3):

Just implement a [custom permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions).

your_app/permissions.py (permissions file for your app)

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class DisableOptionsPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission to disallow all requests for method OPTIONS.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return False
        return True
```

Also set this as the default permission globally, using the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES setting.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'your_app_name.permissions.DisableOptionsPermission',
    )
}
```

This will disallow all incoming requests for OPTIONS method.

Comment: Five years later... just stumbled on this issue and your solution. Still a problem, and this still fixes it. I wonder why it's not the default behavior. Thank you.